# Is storing pyQT widgets in a list bad form?

Tags: python, pyqt

So I am building I program that manages a bunch of custom slider widgets. Currently, I have a slider_container(class) that holds a list of slider objects(class). These slider objects are then inserted into the layout in the main window. This has been working well while I was only adding and moving the position of the sliders up and down. But when I try to delete the sliders, everything goes bad. When ever there the list of slider is manipulated (add, move or delete a slider), the clear and rebuild functions are called in the main window as seen below.

```
def clear_layout(self, layout):
    print "Cleared Layout..."
    while layout.count() > 0:
        item = layout.takeAt(0)
        widget = item.widget()
        if widget is not None:
            widget.deleteLater()

def rebuild_slider_display(self):
    """ Delete the old sliders, then add all the new sliders """
    self.clear_layout(self.slider_layout)


    print "Rebuild layout..."
    print len(self._widgets.widgets)
    for i, widget in enumerate(self._widgets.widgets):
        print widget.slider_name, " ", i
        self.slider_layout.insertWidget(i, widget)
    print "Layout widget count: ", self.slider_layout.count()
```

Currently I am running into this error on this line "self.slider_layout.insertWidget(i, widget)"

```
    RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type SliderWidget has been deleted
```

My hunch is that storing the actual widget in the widget container is bad form. I think what is happening when I deleteLater() a widget, is that it isnt just deleting a widget from the list, it actually deletes the widget class that was store in the widget container itself.

Hopefully that is explained clearly, thanks for your help in advance.

Edit:

Here is the widget class:

```
class SliderWidget(QWidget, ui_slider_widget.Ui_SliderWidget):
""" Create a new slider. """
def __init__(self, name, slider_type, digits, minimum, maximum, value, index, parent=None):
    super(SliderWidget, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)

    self.slider_name = QString(name)
    self.expression = None
    self.accuracy_type = int(slider_type)
    self.accuracy_digits = int(digits)
    self.domain_min = minimum
    self.domain_max = maximum
    self.domain_range = abs(maximum - minimum)
    self.numeric_value = value
    self.index = index

    #self.name.setObjectName(_fromUtf8(slider.name))
    self.update_slider_values()

    self.h_slider.valueChanged.connect(lambda: self.update_spinbox())
    self.spinbox.valueChanged.connect(lambda: self.update_hslider())
    self.edit.clicked.connect(lambda: self.edit_slider())

# A unique has for the slider.    
def __hash__(self):
    return super(Slider, self).__hash__()

# How to compare if this slider is less than another slider.    
def __lt__(self, other):
    r = QString.localAware.Compare(self.name.toLower(), other.name.toLower())
    return True if r < 0 else False

# How to compare if one slider is equal to another slider.    
def __eq__(self, other):
    return 0 == QString.localAwareCompare(self.name.toLower(), other.name.toLower())
```

And here is the actually creation of the widget in the widget container:

```
def add_slider(self, params=None):
    if params:
        new_widget = SliderWidget(params['name'], params['slider_type'], params['digits'], params['minimum'], 
                                    params['maximum'], params['value'], params['index'])
    else:
        new_widget = SliderWidget('Slider_'+str(self.count()+1), 1, 0, 0, 50, 0, self.count())

    #new_widget.h_slider.valueChanged.connect(self.auto_save)
    #new_widget.h_slider.sliderReleased.connect(self.slider_released_save)
    new_widget.move_up.clicked.connect(lambda: self.move_widget_up(new_widget.index))
    new_widget.move_down.clicked.connect(lambda:     self.move_widget_down(new_widget.index))
    self.widgets.append(new_widget)
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: No storing widgets in list by itself is not a problem. This error might come when the parent widget of your child widgets is no longer available. How are you constructing your child slider widgets (i.e. what is the value you pass to the argument 'parent' while constructing the widgets ? )

Comment: Yes, please show how you're constructing the widgets.

Comment: Ok, I updated with code in my comments above. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having was with the way I cleared the layout. It is important to clear the layout from the bottom to the top as seen below.

```
for i in reversed(range(layout.count())): 
    layout.itemAt(i).widget().setParent(None)
```